# Is there a way i can get the url in react before it redirect to other url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router

I am entering some url and that url is redirecting me to login page.  I want after logging in to go to the entered url.  Is there any way to capture the originally entered url before redirecting to the login page.   I am using reactJS.  I want to capture that url so that i can store it in state and send it to the routing component.

`window.location.href`
or
`document.url`
or
`document.referrer`

these all are giving the url for the login page not the original url that user entered.  Is there any way to do so in reactjs?  I am using react-router as well.

Comment: I highly reccomend to use [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Comment: I m using it.  How to do it in that?

Comment: @ZhenyaTelegin I want to capture the url before redirecting, that protected route already has predefined path...Basically i just want that url before redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Routers with

`<Route path="/:page/:id" render={} >`

will solve this problem...and now all that

`window.location.href` or `document.url` or `document.referrer` is giving correct results.

Comment: document.URL capitalized